# Is it possible to install Autofac 4.6.2 in a Xamarin.Forms (PCL) application?

Tags: c#, xamarin, visual-studio-2017, autofac

When I install the latest Autofac (4.6.2) nuget in Visual Studio 2017, I get the following exception:

> Could not install package
>   'System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation 4.0.0'. You are
>   trying to install this package into a project that targets
>   '.NETPortable,Version=v4.5,Profile=Profile111', but the package does
>   not contain any assembly references or content files that are
>   compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the
>   package author.

I poked around on the Xamarin forms and found: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/90997/autofac-installation-issue and the answer I found there was in reference to targeting .NET standard. But, I'm targeting .NET 4.5.

Help?

Answer (score 0):

That seems to be some bug in nuget, discussion of which you can find [here](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/80045/error-using-nuget). Profile you use (111) is compatible with `Autofac 4.6.2`, because Autofac of this version has `net standard 1.1` version, and given profile does support .net standard 1.1. To resolve that issue, add `project.json` file with the following content to your project (build action can be None, and copy to output Do Not Copy):

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "Autofac": "4.6.2"
  },
  "frameworks": {
    ".NETPortable,Version=v4.5,Profile=Profile111": {}
  },
  "supports": {}
}
```

Then close and reopen solution. After that, installing Autofac should be successful.

Comment: nice try, but no cigars... it doesn't work. So, I tried adding: <package id="Autofac" version="4.6.2" targetFramework=".NETPortable,Version=v4.5,Profile=Profile111" /> and doing a Update-Package -reinstall in the Package Manager Console, but go the error: Update-Package : Could not install package 'Autofac 4.6.2'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets '.NETPortable,Version=v4.5,Profile=Profile49', but 
the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.

Comment: @DiranOgunlana Did not forget to close and reopen solution as described? I tested before posting and that works for me.

Comment: @Evk Can confirm this doesn't work targetting v4.5. The required dependency System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation 4.0.0 is not compatible with v4.5. Perhaps the problem lies with VS2015 portable libraries.

Comment: Ignore ^^. It was caused bythe location of project.json. This file *must* be in the project root directory with the project file, .csproj. You can test this by changing the target .NET version in the json. It should report an error targetting the .NETStandard version specified in the json file.